# Map multiple LiveData values into one

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, android-livedata

So, in `iOS` development, I use `ReactiveCocoa` and with that framework I am able to observe multiple `NSObjects` and combine them into a `signal` that returns a a value. Something like this:

```
-(RACSignal *)modelIsValidSignal {

    return [RACSignal combineLatest:@[RACObserve(self,username), RACObserve(self,password), RACObserve(self, busyLoggingIn)]
                             reduce:^id(NSString *username, NSString *password, NSNumber *busyLoggingIn) {
                                 return @((username.length > 0) && (password.length > 0 && busyLoggingIn.boolValue == NO));
                             }];
}
```

So, this will return a `boolean` that is either false or true. As soon as one of the objects state changes, this signal would be notified and the `subscriber (Observer)` would then get that current value of the boolean.

How do I do something similar to this, using `LiveData`? the closest thing to doing this, is `MediatorLiveData` but, I don't see how I can observe multiple `LiveData` events at the same time and then reduce it, like in the above example.

Comment: `LiveData` is designed for fairly simple scenarios. If you need something like this, use RxJava.

Comment: I'ma  little apprehensive, to add RxJava to the mix; as I am trying to lean out dependancies on 3rd part libraries. So, you're saying this is not possible, with LiveData?

Comment: "I am trying to lean out dependancies on 3rd part libraries" -- `LiveData` comes from a library. All of Android development depends upon libraries. Pretty much all modern software development relies upon libraries. "So, you're saying this is not possible, with LiveData?" -- there is nothing "out of the box" that does this. `MediatorLiveData` supports N sources, and so you may be able to work out a transformation that does what you want. My point is that Google has indicated that RxJava is the answer for complex reactive flows.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57819928/4685284

Answer (score 19):

I have made some validation like this

```
var firstName: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
var lastName: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

var personalDetailsValid: MediatorLiveData<Boolean> = MediatorLiveData()

personalDetailsValid.addSource(firstName, {
    personalDetailsValid.value = lastName.value?.isNotBlank() == true && it?.isNotBlank() ?: false
})

personalDetailsValid.addSource(lastName, {
    personalDetailsValid.value = firstName.value?.isNotBlank() == true && it?.isNotBlank() ?: false
})
```

Then I observe the usual way

```
viewModel.personalDetailsValid.observe(this, Observer {
        if (it == true) {
            //Do something
        }
    })
```

I don't know if this is the recommended way of using LiveData and MediatorLiveData but it works for me.

Comment: What about this case: Let's say that we have two differen LiveData sources. F.e. We dont know which source will post the data as first. Also, we need each source to know about the value which is post by the other source. I guess that there must be some solution for that.

Comment: As you can see, I have two seperate sources, and I add them seperately to handle this case. 

We add the source for firstName, so any changes to this variable are validated, but also in conjunction with the lastName variable.

Same applies for the lastNameVariable.

Or am I missing some thing in your question?

Answer (score 4):

Handy and safe solution:

```kotlin
fun <T1, T2, R> combine(
    liveData1: LiveData<T1>,
    liveData2: LiveData<T2>,
    combineFn: (value1: T1?, value2: T2?) -> R
): LiveData<R> = MediatorLiveData<R>().apply {
    addSource(liveData1) {
        value = combineFn(it, liveData2.value)
    }
    addSource(liveData2) {
        value = combineFn(liveData1.value, it)
    }
}

fun <T1, T2, R> Pair<LiveData<T1>, LiveData<T2>>.map(
    combineFn: (value1: T1?, value2: T2?) -> R
) = combine(first, second, combineFn)
```

Use example:

```kotlin
val greetLine = combine(nameLiveData, surnameLiveData) { name, surname ->
   "Hello, $name $surname!"
}

// or using map extension function for consistency with LiveData api
val greetLine = (nameLiveData to surnameLiveData).map { name, surname ->
   "Hello, $name $surname!"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented some util methods for 2 (and more) LiveData values. In works in a RX `Observable.combineLatest()` manner, meaning that it fires updated value if one of the observed `LiveData` will emit any new value. I've added `Function2` as a "combiner" function (in my case I could easily use RX.BiFunction, but `LiveData` can emit `null` values).

Example of combining values from two `LiveData`.

```
object LiveDataUtils {

    fun <T1, T2, R> combineLatest(source1: LiveData<T1>,
                                  source2: LiveData<T2>,
                                  combiner: Function2<T1, T2, R>): LiveData<R> {
        val mediator = MediatorLiveData<R>()

        val combinerFunction = {
            val source1Value = source1.value
            val source2Value = source2.value
            mediator.value = combiner.apply(source1Value, source2Value)
        }

        mediator.addSource(source1) { combinerFunction() }
        mediator.addSource(source2) { combinerFunction() }
        return mediator
    }

}

interface Function2<T1, T2, R> {
    fun apply(t1: T1?, t2: T2?): R
}
```

Comment: Nice, but how to handle result from ViewModel?
What is should in block? How to grab value?