# How to combine the result of 2 LiveData fields into another LiveData field of a different type

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-livedata-transformations

I have a ViewModel class with 2 livedata observables (eg `a` and `b`) that are both of a nullable type and
I want to add a new boolean observable (eg `c`) that is true whenever both `a` and `b` are not null, and false otherwise.

I was recommended to use a LiveData Transformation to achieve this but I'm not quite sure how that would work. With a map transformation, I can only ever transform between a single observer, but I can't add multiple sources.

Then that lead me to looking at representing `c` as a MediatorLiveData and add `a` and `b` as sources but then that relies on the fact that they are all of the same type, so I'm not sure if I can use that either.

What's the idiomatic way to accomplish this?

Comment: do you want an answer in java or kotlin?

Comment: I'm looking for something in kotlin

Comment: check this out for using Transformation or MediatorLiveData: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572913/livedata-transformations-map-with-multiple-arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the recommended approach for kotlin  is [StateFlow](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow). It is like a liveData but more kotlin idiomatic.

this is an example of combining a String flow with an Int flow into a Boolean flow

```
class ExampleViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    private val _a = MutableStateFlow<Int>(2)
    val a = _a.asLiveData()
    private val _b = MutableStateFlow<String>("example")
    val b = _b.asLiveData()
    // this will emit a value at each update of either _a or _b
    val c = _a.combine(_b) { a, b -> a > b.length }.asLiveData()
    // this will emit a value at each update of _a
    val d = _a.zip(_b) { a, b -> a > b.length }.asLiveData()
    // this will emit a value at each update of _b
    val e = _b.zip(_a) { b, a -> a > b.length }.asLiveData()
    // this is the same as d
    val f = _a.map { it > _b.value.length }.asLiveData()
}
```

Learn more [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html#composing-multiple-flows)